# The strcpy function causing unwanted vars being modified

Tags: c

Sorry if its too basic but i couldn't solve it . When i do the `strcpy` i get other variables right after it being changed .

```
//global
char incomingData[250] = {0};   //data is never exceeds 50.
```

then incomingData is filled with data and ..

```
handleIncomingData(incomingData);

void handleIncomingData(char *incoming)
{
    parseGetRespondHeader(incoming); //also strcpy strings into "incoming"
    char *header = strtok (incoming,":");
    char *dataA=strtok (NULL, ":");
    char *dataB=strtok (NULL, ":");

    if(strstr(header, PROTOCOL_SET_WIFI_CONNECTION ) != NULL)
    {
        if(checkConnection(dataA,dataB))
            strcpy(incoming,"connected"); // REMOVING THIS LINE SOLVES IT
```

The marked line is causing other unrelated pointers to change their value (the var before that line and after it is different )

The `checkConnection` function is NOT doing anything to `dataA` and `dataB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok()` does not create new allocations.   `dataA` is pointing to (one past) where the first ':' **was** in incoming, and `dataB` is pointing to (one past) where the second ':' **was**.

`strcpy(incoming, "connected")` will overwrite dataA (and maybe dataB) if your first token (pointed to by `header`) is shorter than `strlen("connected")`

Comment: thats right! dataA is really the problem ! can you explain a little bit ??

Comment: oh got it ! so how should i change that ?

Comment: @Curnelious strtok does not put the token in new memory. It simply generates pointers to where the tokens in the old string were. so if you use strtok(str,','); on a string thats "str,as", the first return value will point to the "s" in the string. the second will point to the "a".

Comment: `strtok()` takes your initial pointer you pass into it, and modifies THAT memory.   It converts your delimiter to a `\0` in THAT memory.  The next call returns the address one past the previous delimiter, and does the whole thing again.

Comment: @Curnelious just copy your incoming into another string entirely using `strcpy` and then use that string for strtok instead.

Comment: Yeah, probably the easiest.   'strdup()' and then strtok() that to death.   make sure to free() the ptr returned by strdup() **AFTER** you're done with all the tokens (or make copies of the tokens with strdup())

Comment: oh great thank you all! i couldn't be more happy, took me hours... i will accept your answer when it lets me (2 minutes)

Comment: I have tried this -   char *copyIncoming; and then -strcpy(copyIncoming,incoming); and then - parseGetRespondHeader(copyIncoming); but i am getting different results... is this wrong again ?

Answer (score 2):

Those pointers are not unrelated. They are all pointing inside the string.

The pointers don't change their value. But the value where their point to can easily change if you overwrite it.

Check the documentation of [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok).

Comment: what pointers ? Sorry but your answer is not so clear to me understanding what is wrong with the code.. the pointer that is being modified is not even shown here.

Comment: got it, thanks... i missed this fact that it actually not creating a new array

Answer (score 2):

Your other pointers are all pointing to portions of the same string `incoming`. Keep in mind `strtok` modifies the variable you pass to it.

to solve this, just copy your string `incoming` into another string using `strcpy` and then use that other string for your `strtok` operation